# Test 32-Bit ODBC Connection using CMD/Powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd, odbc, registry

I have scoured the web for a way to do this but i'm at a loss so im hoping that you guys might be able to help me out!

I am trying to add a data source to ODBC using PowerShell, i have managed to add it using registry entries, however for some reason it requires you to test connection otherwise it doesn't pick it up properly.

To create the entry i am using the below code.

```
regedit /s .\dsn.reg
regedit /s .\ODBCDataSources.reg

start-sleep -Seconds 2

#Edit ODBC
$registryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI\AutoFlow"

$Name = "EngineName"

$value = "$AFDBName"

New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $value -PropertyType String -Force | Out-Null
```

And to get around the need of testing connection at the moment i am launching ODBC so that they can test the connection and it will wait for ODBC to close before continuing, but obviously this isn't the best way to go about it.

Any help you guys can give would be much appreciated!